# Flot re-draw single series

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am looking for a way to re-draw a single series in Flot, I know I can use plot.setData(newData) and plot.draw() to re-draw all the data series but I have one series with 100,000+ points so I dont really want to re-draw this one every time

At a guess I could use the drawSeries hook but Im not sure how to implement this?

Thanks in advance

David

Comment: well its seems you cant do this, I got by drawing a second graph and positioning it absolutely on top of the first with a transparent background